# JQuery and Patial view in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Belong to this article [Jquery Partial View](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/JQueryPartial.aspx)

What should i do when i want to submit the value fill from user
and sent it to the ActionResult controller that return the partial view

-- View Code that call the controller (from article)

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   $('#centerbody').load('/Custom/CustomAction', function(html) {
       $('#centerbody')[0].value = html;  
   });
</script>
```

-- Controller Action with no parameter (from article)

```
public ActionResult CustomAction()
{
  return View("_CustomParialView");
}
```

Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function represents a hash allowing you to pass additional parameters along with the AJAX request:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#centerbody').load(
        '/Custom/CustomAction', 
        {
            // suppose that you have a text input with id: someInputId
            // The value entered by the user in this field will be
            // passed along the request in someParam
            someParam: $('#someInputId').val()
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

And in your controller action you could add `someParam` in order to retrieve the value passed by the AJAX call:

```
public ActionResult CustomAction(string someParam)
{
    // someParam will be passed from jQuery
    return PartialView("_CustomParialView");
}
```